# Extend the schema of grahpql in magento 2.4

Tags: php, magento, graphql, magento2, magento2.4

Good morning,

I have been trying to extend an schema in magento for a while.

I have used the official documentation already and It doesn't work,

I have been seeing a lot of pages and tutorial without any results.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have some code we can take a look at? The more the details easier it'll be

Comment: Basically everything from this pages:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/develop/extend-existing-schema.html#extend-the-schema.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/290911/how-to-extend-or-override-default-graphql-query-mutation-or-schema
https://larsroettig.dev/how-to-create-a-graph-ql-endpoint-for-magento-2-3

If you have done it before can you just show me how did you do it and the process you follow, or at least a page where It guide you step to step?